# Microsoft Word Automation / interop Win32 API issue

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop, ms-word

I am trying to control the window location of Word.

My WinForms (C#) application takes up the bottom half of the screen and launches an instance of Word. I need this instance to take the upper half of the screen.

This cannot be controlled through interop so I managed to to get the Window Handle of the Word instance. Then I tried using SetWindowPos, SetWindowsLong, etc. in various ways but without any visible results.

Instead of posting buggy code all over again, I wanted a fresh start so any suggestions are welcome from people who have achieved something like this.

Comment: You can embed word as an activex control.  See if that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Application.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.move) method. or set [Application.Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.top) or [Application.Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.left) properties directly. your code can be like this:

```
private Word.Application WordApp = new Word.Application();

    ...

private void buttonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        object fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        object visible = true;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        WordApp.Visible = true;
        Word.Document aDoc = 
                        WordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing,
                                               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                               ref missing, ref missing, ref visible);
        aDoc.Activate();
        WordApp.Top = 0;
    }
}
```

dont forget to add **Microsoft Word Object Library** to your references and using related namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the Move and Dimension properties. Will give that a try and revert back soon.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the answer. I noticed though that when I calculate the size of my screen using Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, I have to subtract about 120 pixels to make it fit on the screen vertically. Any ideas what could cause this?